# Why does ENV['FOO'] = true raise an exception in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
ENV['FOO'] = true
```

Raises `no implicit conversion of true into String`

```
puts ENV.class
Object < BasicObject
```

Array access methods are not part of BasicObject.

Not sure if this is coming from Rack, Rack Test or another gem.

ruby 2.2.3p173
rack (1.6.0)
rack-test (0.6.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [`ENV class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ENV.html) isn't just an object or an hash: *ENV is a hash-like accessor for environment variables.*

It is obvious that it is not a real heash, because the setter method (`ENV[name] = value`) tries to cast the value to string.

Furthermore it is worth noting that it is missing many methods a normal hash would have.

Comment: ENV is a special-case. It's not its own class, it's an accessor to the system environment, given hash-like accessors for convenience.

Comment: `ENV` is a very special thing. You might want to read the comments in [hash.c#L4122](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L4122) and [hash.c#L4173](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L4173).

Comment: @spickermann - Oh, that's where it is. I was looking for where Hash is defined.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand what `ENV` is: It's the variables defined in your shell, which lies beneath your script and  Ruby, and will be made available to your running script or to any sub-shells you create.

That environment only knows about strings, values expressed as 'true' or 'false', not as objects like Ruby's `true` or `false`.

Saying `ENV['foo'] = true` is an attempt to assign a Ruby object and fails. Use `ENV['foo'] = 'true'` instead.

Here's a little example of how you can use it. I have a single line of Ruby code in a file called "test.rb":

```
puts ENV['foo']
```

If I run that code using the following command in a shell:

```
foo=bar ruby test.rb
```

The Ruby script outputs the value of `ENV['foo']`:

```
bar
```

That's because `foo=bar` initialized the system environment variable `foo` to 'bar' prior to handing off control to Ruby.

I can use that same variable to look at the value in a sub-shell also. Changing the Ruby script to:

```
ENV['foo'] = 'baz'
puts `echo $foo`
```

and running it sets the environment variable 'foo' to 'bar' prior to giving Ruby control, then Ruby changes it to 'baz' then executes the sub-shell to echo the output of the variable, which Ruby captures because I'm using backticks:

```
foo=bar ruby test.rb
```

resulting in:

```
baz
```

being printed. Even though I'd originally set the variable to 'bar', the script set it to 'baz', which only the sub-shell could see.

I think a good argument could be made that writing to ENV should automatically use `to_s` to avoid this, but it's one of many gotcha's found in any programming language.

Comment: Yes, `to_s`. `to_str` is used in places, but I meant `to_s` for this.